# Laravel 5.3 distinct count, using eloquent instead of Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, count, eloquent

Come across a weird issue, where i originally tried

```
$usersWithAnswersCount = GameResult::where([
    'school_id' => null,
    'season_id' => $this->season->id
])
->groupBy('user_id')
->count();
```

My table looks like

[image]

However I was getting back the result `"1"` when it should have been returning back `"2"`

When I inspect what the query that ran was it was `select count(*) as aggregate from game_results where (school_id is null and season_id = '1') group by user_id` - which if i run directly as a mysql query returns back 2!!

So it looks like something within eloquent is changing my 2 into a 1 :(

However if i change this into the DB Query Builder and write out

```
$usersWithAnswersCount = DB::table('game_results')
->selectRaw('count(distinct user_id) as count')
->where([
    'school_id' => null,
    'season_id' => $this->season->id
])
->first()->count;
```

I get back `"2"` which is what I expected.

However I'm unclear why the Eloquent method fails, and what I can do to fix it if its possible.

Comment: How are you outputting these results?

Comment: using mixture of `dump($usersWithAnswersCount);` and `dd($usersWithAnswersCount);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you making is not correct for use case, you can see the difference.

```
select count(*) as aggregate from game_results 
where (school_id is null and season_id = '1') 
group by user_id order by user_id asc;
```

will return two rows

```
aggregate
1,
2
```

Eloquent picks first and return which is 1.

```
select count(*) as aggregate from game_results 
where (school_id is null and season_id = '1') 
group by user_id order by user_id desc;
```

will return rows as

```
agrregate
2,
1
```

Eloquent will result 2 in this case.

What you want is count of (query) which will be again 2.

Getting It? what you want is **DISTINCT**

```
$usersWithAnswersCount = GameResult::where([
    'school_id' => null,
    'season_id' => $this->season->id 
])
->distinct('user_id')
->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel's `distinct()` method to get distinct records from the Database.

**UPDATE**

You can try this:

```
$usersWithAnswersCount = GameResult::where([
    'school_id' => null,
    'season_id' => $this->season->id
])
->distinct('user_id')
->count();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The first distinct one works, i believe @anwerjunaid posted the same which worked

Comment: Yup that's my bad, I've updated the code, if you've downvoted it can you please undo that as now my answer is valid :D

Comment: PlusOne for first distinct, second still has flaws.

Comment: The `distinct()` query builder function accepts no arguments... this will not work. You want to put the column in the `count()` function ie `->distinct()->count('user_id');`